PyQGIS affine transformation scaling problems
I want to create a bounding box around a selected feature and scale this bbox to a certain factor. The input feature results[f'{name_lower}'] is a valid polygon and does not produce any problems by itself. However the affinetransform algorithm does not scale the feature on every axis but rather multiplies the coordinates by that factor as can be seen in the screenshots (first picture is the original bbox, the second the scaled one. Am I using the tool wrong or is it the wrong tool for my task?
QGIS version 3.34.6 LTR
                        # Creating a bounding box around the selected feature
                        alg_params = {
                            'INPUT': results[f'{name_lower}'],  
                            'CRS': 4326,
                            'OUTPUT': f'memory:bounding_box'
                        }
                        outputs['bounding_box'] = processing.run('native:boundingboxes', alg_params,context=context, feedback=feedback,is_child_algorithm=True)
                        results['bounding_box'] = outputs['bounding_box']['OUTPUT']

                        # Applying transformation
                        alg_params = {
                            'INPUT': results['bounding_box'],
                            'DELTA_X': 0,
                            'DELTA_Y': 0,
                            'DELTA_Z': 0,
                            'DELTA_M': 0,
                            'SCALE_X': 2,  # Scale factor in X direction
                            'SCALE_Y': 2,  # Scale factor in Y direction
                            'SCALE_Z': 0,
                            'SCALE_M': 0,
                            'ROTATION_Z': 0,
                            'CRS': 4326,
                            'OUTPUT': f'memory:scaled_bounding_box'
                        }
                        outputs['scaled_bounding_box'] = processing.run('native:affinetransform', alg_params,context=context, feedback=feedback,is_child_algorithm=True)
                        results['scaled_bounding_box'] = outputs['scaled_bounding_box']['OUTPUT']
                        temporary_layer_names.append("scaled_bounding_box")
                        feedback.pushInfo("created scaled_bounding_box")




It doesn't work as you think it does, it scales x from the crs origin (here it is 0) so new_x = (x-0) * SCALE_X + DELTA_X. pour scale_x=2: 8.31 -> 16.62. It performs all transformations on the layer, not each feature, so scaling isn't centered on the centroid of the feature's geometry but the layer's crs origin.

Yes, I played around with that one until I figured out what happened with my polygon. Now I settled on using a buffer, but it is really frustrating how many super basic functionalities are still missing from qgis. (except I just wasn't able to find the right one)

This seems a pretty useful and simple task to be in qgis. Though, if you know some programming with the pyqgis api, doing this is pretty simple in less than a dozen lines of code.
